# Which method is appropriate for using the pattern of a high frequency timeseries dataset to interpolate a low frequency timeseries dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, python, interpolation

I have a low temporal frequency irregular dataset with a value available every 40 to 48 days. I have another set of time-series data over the same period at 12 day frequency. The pattern of the two datasets are related (but not the values), and I'd like to use the pattern of the 12-day dataset to interpolate the 40-48 day data to a higher temporal resolution (e.g. daily or 10 days). I'll be implementing the analysis in Python (or R would be fine too), but I'm not sure of which method I should be looking to use. Is there an existing Python or R package that can be used for this kind of interpolation? Any advice would be much appreciated.